# How to add a link in MediaWiki VisualEditor Toolbar?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor

I`m trying to insert a custom link to a special page in VisualEditor toolbar. See the image below.

[image: Link Position]
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj44G.png)

I googled a lot but without success. Someone please give a path...

Comment: Look for the implementation of the editor in your media wiki. I think it is Tinymce.

Comment: are you asking about Visual studio editor?

Comment: @Sagar It's about https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor

Answer (score 5):

My answer is based on the following resources:

- [MediaWiki core JS doc (ooui-js)](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/js/)
- [VisualEditor JS doc](https://doc.wikimedia.org/VisualEditor/master/) (+ reading code of both repositories used for VE, [mediawiki/extension/VisualEditor](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-VisualEditor) and [VisualEditor](https://github.com/wikimedia/VisualEditor))

Also, I'm pretty sure, that there is no documented way of adding a tool to the toolbar in VE, as far as I know. Although it's possible to add a tool to a group, which is already added, mostly used for the "Insert" tool group, like in [Syntaxhighlight_GeSHi](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi/blob/master/modules/VisualEditor/ve.ui.MWSyntaxHighlightInspectorTool.js#L24)). There is, probably, a much easier or "better" way of doing this :)

First, VisualEditor provides a way to load additional modules (called *plugins*) when the main part of VE loads (mostly, when you click the "Edit" button). The modules needs to be registered via the global variable `$wgVisualEditorPluginModules` (or the equivalent in extension.json, if you're using the new extension registration). In your extension registration file, you should initialize a module (with your required script files to add the tool) and add it as a VE plugin.

Example PHP (old extension registration via PHP files):

```
// other setup...
$wgResourceModules['ext.extName.visualeditor'] = array(
    'localBasePath' => __DIR__,
    'remoteExtPath' => 'extName'
    'dependencies' => array(
        'ext.visualEditor.mwcore',
    ),
    'scripts' => array(
        'javascripts/ve.ui.ExtNameTool.js',
    ),
    'messages' => array(
        'extname-ve-toolname',
    ),
);
$wgVisualEditorPluginModules[] = 'ext.extName.visualeditor';
// other setup...
```

extension.json (new JSON-based extension registration):

```
// other setup...
"ResourceModules": {
    "ext.geshi.visualEditor": {
        "scripts": [
            "javascripts/ve.ui.ExtNameTool.js"
        ],
        "dependencies": [
            "ext.visualEditor.mwcore"
        ],
        "messages": [
            "extname-ve-toolname"
        ]
   }
},
"VisualEditorPluginModules": [
    "ext.extName.visualeditor"
],
// other setup...
```

Now, if VE starts, it will load your module, named `ext.extName.visualeditor` in this example, with the script `ve.ui.ExtNameTool.js`. In this script, you can now do, what ever you want. As an example, this is a way to add a new module to the end of the toolgroup list in the toolbar:

Example of ve.ui.ExtNameTool.js:

```
( function () {
    // create a new class, which will inherit ve.ui.Tool,
    // which represents one tool
    ve.ui.extNameTool = function extNameTool( toolGroup, config ) {
        // parent constructor
        ve.ui.extNameTool.super.apply( this, arguments );
        // the tool should be enabled by default, enable it
        this.setDisabled( false );
    }
    // inherit ve.ui.Tool
    OO.inheritClass( ve.ui.extNameTool, ve.ui.Tool );
    // every tool needs at least a name, or an icon
    // (with the static property icon)
    ve.ui.extNameTool.static.name = 'extname';
    // don't add the tool to a named group automatically
    ve.ui.extNameTool.static.autoAddToGroup = false;
    // prevent this tool to be added to a catch-all group (*),
    although this tool isn't added to a group
    ve.ui.extNameTool.static.autoAddToCatchall = false;
    // the title of the group (it's a message key,
    // which should be added to the extensions i18n
    // en.json file to be translateable)
    // can be a string, too
    ve.ui.extNameTool.static.title =
        OO.ui.deferMsg( 'extname-ve-toolname' );
    // onSelect is the handler for a click on the tool
    ve.ui.extNameTool.prototype.onSelect = function () {
        // show an alert box only, but you can do anything
        alert( 'Hello' );
        this.setActive( false );
    }
    // needs to be overwritten, but does nothing so far
    ve.ui.extNameTool.prototype.onUpdateState = function () {
    ve.ui.extNameTool.super.prototype.onUpdateState.apply( this, arguments );
    }
    // the tool needs to be registered to the toolFactory
    // of the toolbar to be reachable with the given name
    ve.ui.toolFactory.register( ve.ui.extNameTool );
    // add this tool to the toolbar
    ve.init.mw.Target.static.toolbarGroups.push( {
        // this will create a new toolgroup with the tools
        // named in this include directive. The naem is the name given
        // in the static property of the tool
        include: [ 'extname' ]
    } );
} )();
```

After installing the extension in your `LocalSettings.php` and starting VE, you should see a new tool in the toolbar with the given name. Clicking it will show an alert box with content "Hello". Like written in the inline comments: In the click handler (`onSelect`) you can do whatever you want, e.g. open a link in a new tab, e.g. to a Special page. To get the link to a special page I would suggest to use `mw.Title` to get a localized namespace. For example:

```
var relativeUrl = mw.Title.newFromText( 'RecentChanges', -1 ).getUrl();
```

The first parameter of `mw.Title.newFromText()` is the name of the page, the second parameter is the ID of the namespace (-1 is the default for special pages and should always work).

I hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I understand your question entirely. It is as simple as selecting some text, clicking the chain icon, then clicking the `External Link` tab and pasting your link there.

---

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think the question is how to add a link to the VE toolbar, not to the editable content :)