# Is There some easy way to create custom toolbar in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I want to add a button to auto insert "" label. 
But I don't understand the wiki. How can I deal with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is on a MediaWiki installation where you have administrator rights the quickest solution (for wikitext editing) is to add `"+"` to `MediaWiki:Edittools`.

More in-depth help if you want to add a button to e.g. the top toolbar more detailed instructions exists at [Manual:Custom edit buttons](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Custom_edit_buttons) over at mediaiwki.org.

For VisualEditor there might be some info over at [How to add a link in MediaWiki VisualEditor Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272435/how-to-add-a-link-in-mediawiki-visualeditor-toolbar)