# MediaWiki VisualEditor: Adding custom widgets

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor

I'm currently trying to add text/background colors to VisualEditor. I think the right approach is to add a widgets like the one the language annotation uses, but I am stuck.

Maybe someone added the color functionality or custom widgets to the VisualEditor and may share his/her experience with me?

That's my current state:

I think I need to replicate the Inspector-class (besides others), but that's the one I'm stuck on. I copied the `LanguageInspector.js`, removed everything about `dir` and changed everything from `language` to `textColor` (that's how my annotation-class is named). But when I add it to the VisualEditor.php, I get a

```
Error: Module ext.visualEditor.core has failed dependencies
```

Comment: What is your actual code? Some months ago, I wrote this answer, which maybe helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272435/how-to-add-a-link-in-mediawiki-visualeditor-toolbar/31830867#31830867

Comment: @Florian thanks for your feedback. I actually did read your post already (the content regarding VE is quite limited ;)). You do describe how to extend VE nicely, but I'm past that state as I am trying to replicate the language-widget-system specifically.